# Replacement for LIKE in sql

Tags: sql, automated-tests, sql-like

I am using a tool Automate 9 which doesn't allow me to use % in my sql query ,i want to know if i can match a string without using % in LIKE command .

or if i can match the string by any other command but the only thing is that i cannot use % anywhere in the query.

say for example, i have the below command with me.

```
CASE WHEN l.something LIKE '%this.needs.tomacth%' THEN 'thisone'
```

but this gives error when used in automate 9 tool because of  these % wildcards.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What's available varies widely between them, and therefore any answer would need to know what you're using specifically. Please [edit] and add a tag for the **specific** DBMS you're using (not just those that sound similar).

Comment: If you are using MySQL, try [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: What error are you receiving when you attempt to run this query via Automate 9 and what DBMS Automate 9 connected to?

Comment: will it be possible to execute SQL query in oracle database ,which is installed on Linux server, through automate 9 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the percent sign in automate by typing it twice. So this should work:

```
CASE WHEN l.something LIKE '%%this.needs.tomacth%%' THEN 'thisone'
```

Comment: Thanks Caius , it worked with this resolution.
Could you help me with two more queries i have for automate 9 .
1. how can i modify the name of excel sheet with the current date [Myexcel_2016/07/15] where i am saving the query output, task will be run on  a daily basis , so i want to update the excel name everytime the query run so that it reflects current date in the name.?

2. This is an another automation which i am working on..

is this possible by automate 9 to run an SQL script on an ORACLE Database which is installed on LINUX server ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server has a function [`CHARINDEX()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('this.needs.tomacth', l.something) THEN 'thisone'
```

MySQL, Oracle, and SQLite have a function `INSTR()`
 [MySQL INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr),
 [Oracle INSTR()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm),
 [SQLite INSTR()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

```
CASE WHEN INSTR(l.something, 'this.needs.tomacth') THEN 'thisone'
```

PostgreSQL and IBM DB2 have a function `POSITION()`
 [PostgreSQL POSITION()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html),
 [IBM DB2 POSITION()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023195.html)

```
CASE WHEN POSITION('this.needs.tomacth' IN l.something) THEN 'thisone'
```